# android The specified child already has a parent. You must call removeView() on the child's parent first. on listView adaper

Tags: android, listview

I've a listview ,I use an adapter for adding data . I want to add some textviews to somerows dynamically ,this is my code :

```
public class TimeListAdapter extends CursorAdapter {

    public TimeListAdapter(Context context, Cursor c) {
        super(context, c);
    }

    public class ViewHolder {
        LinearLayout extra;

        public ViewHolder(View row) {
            extra = (LinearLayout) row.findViewById(R.id.extras);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public View newView(Context context, Cursor arg1, ViewGroup arg2) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        View row = inflater.inflate(R.layout.sabadrow, arg2, false);
        ViewHolder holder = new ViewHolder(row);
        row.setTag(holder);
        return row;
    }

    @Override
    public void bindView(View v, Context context, Cursor c) {
        ViewHolder holder = (ViewHolder) v.getTag();
        holder.extra.setTag(c.getInt(0));

        LayoutInflater vi = (LayoutInflater) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        View v2 = vi.inflate(R.layout.curstomrow, null,false);

        TextView tvcheck = (TextView) v2.findViewById(R.id.tvcheck);
        tvcheck.setTypeface(typeface);
        Cursor c2=db.getServices(c.getInt(0));
        int i=0;
        for (c2.moveToFirst(); !c2.isAfterLast(); c2.moveToNext()) {
            tvcheck.setText(c2.getString(3));

            holder.extra.addView(v2);
            holder.extra.refreshDrawableState();
        }
    }
}
```

When I run my application , I get these errors :

```
 java.lang.IllegalStateException: The specified child already has a parent. You must call removeView() on the child's parent first.
```

What am I doing is wrong ? How can I solve this problem ?
thanks

Answer (score 0):

I think kts easier to use 2 seperate xml files and choose between them instead of adding extra views

Answer (score 0):

You created (inflated) only a single new view, you need to create a new one in each iteration. Something like this:

```
for (c2.moveToFirst(); !c2.isAfterLast(); c2.moveToNext()) {
    View v2 = vi.inflate(R.layout.curstomrow, null,false);
    holder.extra.addView(v2);
    holder.extra.refreshDrawableState();
}
```